# Angularjs - How to insert a directive inside a panel on a particular position everytime when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and I am trying to insert a progress bar directive inside a panel which is at the bottom of the page. When a button is clicked , I want to add the progress bar to the panel in the bottom left .

Likewise when the button is clicked again, a second bar should get added to the panel in the bottom left position in the panel ,and the first bar should move to right and get placed near the second bar and so on .

For every click , the current bar should the first in the panel from left and the older ones should move right and be next to the current bar

Currently the panel I have is a css panel which is page responsive and the progress bar directive creates a progress bar and updates it with a percentage

I am not sure how to achieve the above functionality in Angularjs. Please let me know if I want to post the code for the panel and directive here. Your help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code as a snippet.

Comment: What you achieve so far?

Comment: Use the `ng-repeat` directive with an array and `unshift` the new progress bar into the array.